# Question about Flask + Multiprocessing + Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask

I am trying to make an app using Flask + multiprocess + tensorflow and I encounter 2 problem.

1. How can I caught KeyboardInterrupt **before** the function was called but **after** the pool be created, cause I only saw a lot of example and put the appy in try block. And I will like to know how can I catch after it created and before it be called.
2. Another thing I realize is that when I create 4 pool and all 4 pool will **preload** the tensorflow package, and 1 process cost almost 1G memory space, but I want to create a pool without doing anything about tensorflow, and that will be a resource waste, is there any good solution to create a pool with out tensorflow?

```
import multiprocessing
from flask import Flask,request, jsonify
from mllibrary.mllibrary import MLLibrary

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile('server_config.py')
ml_library = MLLibrary()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        ml_process_pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2)
        debug = bool(app.config.get('DEBUG'))
        app.run(host=app.config.get('HOST'), port=int(app.config.get('PORT')), debug=debug)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        ml_process_pool.terminate()
        print("KeyboardInterrupt catch in main")
```